# what is a good logic with ngif to check if the user role is something and title is something

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

There are three `item titles: Admin, Dashboards, Create Job`. For `Admin`, I want to see all items, for others I want to show items without `title having Admin`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuHorService.menuList$ | async">
    <ng-container *ngIf="role=='user' && (item.title=='Dashboards' || item.title == 'Create Job')">
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.title" [ngTemplateOutlet]="menuTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ item: item }"></ng-container>  
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="role=='admin' && (item.title=='Dashboards' || item.title == 'Create Job' || item.title == 'Admin')">
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.title" [ngTemplateOutlet]="menuTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ item: item }"></ng-container>  
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What you can do is to create new pipe which will filter your array `menuList$` and put it after `async` pipe. Inside new pipe you can handle logic what items show based on user role.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid complex logic like this in your view. Instead, append the logic to your observable call. For this reason I would also avoid calling your service directly from your HTML.

```js
constructor(private menuHorService: MenuHorService) {}

menuList$: Observable<any[]>; // TODO: use type
role = 'user'; // TODO: implement

ngOnInit() {
  this.menuList$ = this.menuHorService.menuList$.pipe(
    map((menuList: any[]) => menuList.filter(x => this.showMenuItem(x)))
  );
}

private showMenuItem(menuItem: any): boolean {
  return menuItem.title !== 'Admin' || this.role === 'admin';
}
```

And then your HTML becomes trivial. For example:

```html
<!-- dummy html -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuList$ | async">
  <p>
    {{item | json}}
  </p>
</ng-container>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mtkxs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuHorService.menuList$ | async">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(role === 'admin' || item.title !== 'Admin')">
    <!-- any thing -->
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```